# Script works in firefox scratchpad but not in greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, document-ready

So i have this script:

```
links = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb');
for (var i=links.length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
links[i].href=links[i].href+'/popout';
}
```

that works in scratchpad after the page, i want modified, is loaded.

But when i put it in greasemonkey it runs before page is fully loaded and elements i need to mod are not there and it doesn't work.

Here is gs script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        popout
// @namespace   PylonPants
// @include     http://*.twitch.tv/directory/*
// @version     1

// ==/UserScript==

//if ('loading' == document.readyState) {
//  alert("This script is running at document-start time.");
//} else {
//  alert("This script is running with document.readyState: " + document.readyState);
//}
// script runs at readyState = interactive and that brakes it
// do not know how to make it wait till complete

links = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb');
alert(links[0]); // i get "undefined"
for (var i=links.length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
alert('the script works'); //i never reach here
alert(links[i].href); // nor here
links[i].href=links[i].href+'/popout';
}
alert('crazy'); // i get this then the page loads fully.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script must wait for the page's javascript to load those thumbnails.  The simplest, most robust way, to do that, is to use [the waitForKeyElements() utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891).

Here's ***a complete script*** that uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and `waitForKeyElements` to alter those `href`s:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        popout
// @namespace   PylonPants
// @include     http://*.twitch.tv/directory/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("a.thumb", adjustLinkHrefs);

function adjustLinkHrefs (jNode) {
    var newAddr = jNode.attr ("href") + '/popout';
    jNode.attr ("href", newAddr);
}
```